# Getting control over color the end-point markers in a time line plot

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

I made a `TimeLinePlot` to visualise intervals. Each interval starts with a marker en end with one.

For example:

```
TimelinePlot[
  {{Interval[{"Mar 20, 1990", "Jul 11, 2008"}]}, 
   {Interval[{"Sep 17, 1990", "Mar 14, 2005"}]}},
  PlotMarkers -> "Filled"]
```

This produces

[image]

Each interval line has a different color. I want both interval Lines to start with a red bullet and finish with a blue one.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = {{Interval[{"Mar 20, 1990", "Jul 11, 2008"}]}, 
  {Interval[{"Sep 17, 1990", "Mar 14, 2005"}]}};
```

**1.** You can pre-process input data to replace `{Interval[{a, b}]}` with `{Interval[{a,b}], Style[a, Red], Style[b, Blue]}` and use the option `Spacings`  as follows:

```
data2 = data /. { i : Interval[{a_, b_}]} :> {i, Style[a, Red], Style[b, Blue]};

TimelinePlot[data2, Spacings -> {1, 0}, PlotMarkers -> {"Filled", .02}]
```

[image]

**2.** Alternatively, you can post-process `TimelinePlot` output to insert the desired directives:

```
tlp = TimelinePlot[data, PlotMarkers -> "Filled"];

Show[tlp, 
 Graphics[Cases[tlp, 
    PointBox[x_] :> Thread[{AbsolutePointSize[10], {Red, Blue}, Point /@ x}], All]]]
```

[image]

**3.** Use `data` to construct graphics primitives with desired styles to be used as `Epilog` in `TimelinePlot`:

```
epilog = MapIndexed[Thread[{AbsolutePointSize[10], {Red, Blue}, 
     Point /@ Thread[{#, #2[[1]]}]}] &, 
  Flatten[data] /. Interval -> Map[AbsoluteTime]];

TimelinePlot[data, Epilog -> epilog]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, I like the first one. But, how is the transformation if the dataset looks like data = {Interval[{"Mar 20, 2020", "Jul 11, 2020"}], 
  Interval[{"Sep 17, 2020", "Sep 20, 2020"}]}

Comment: @MichielvanMens, you can use `datab = {Interval[{"Mar 20, 1990", "Jul 11, 2008"}], 
   Interval[{"Sep 17, 1990", "Mar 14, 2005"}]};
datab2 = datab /.  i : Interval[{a_, b_}] :> {i, Style[a, Red], Style[b, Blue]};
TimelinePlot[datab2, Spacings -> {1, 0},  PlotMarkers -> {"Filled", .02}]`